# Virtual environment does not open when executing shell script in Jenkins docker container

Tags: python, shell, pytest, jenkins-docker

To run my python tests I created a freestyle project in Jenkins and wrote a script like this:

```
. .env/bin/activate
   pip install pytest
pytest --alluredir='FINAL/ws/allure-results' ./FINAL/autotests
```

But the build crashes with the "Can't open" error:
[image: "Can't open" error:]

Comment: Add `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of the script step. Then try to execute.

Comment: You welcome. I have added it as answer, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by adding `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of the script step and then try to execute.